# React iterate through an object inside of an array in JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, object, iteration

I am working on a React project and attempting to pull JSON data from an API. I have a searchbar and I want to make it so the user can type a term into the searchbar and then that term is sent to a NASA API and returns the appropriate results.

The NASA API looks like [this](https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=mars). It has an array of objects and that's where I'm running into problems. I am having trouble mapping through the object (I know that .map only works on arrays and I most likely need to use Object.keys to iterate through the objects). I am having trouble accomplishing this.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
loadSearchResults = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
var search = this.state.value;

axios.get(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=` + `search`)
  .then(res => {
    //const results = res.data.collection.items;
    const results = res.data.collection.items;
    this.setState = ({
      results,
      header: "Search Results"
    });
    console.log(results);
  });
```

}

I am able to console.log the data but I'm not sure how to iterate through the objects and get to the data I want. I've tried variations of setting const results to something like const results = res.data.collection.items.map() or res.data.collection.Object.keys() etc... but I can't figure it out.

How can I pull the data from the data array object? I.e. title. descriptiong, etc...

```
"items": [
  {
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/video/50 Years of Mars Exploration /50 Years of Mars Exploration .srt",
        "rel": "captions"
      }
    ],
    "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/video/50 Years of Mars Exploration /collection.json",
    "data": [
      {
        "center": "HQ",
        "description": "2015 marks 50 years of successful NASA missions to Mars starting with Mariner 4 in 1965. Since then, a total of 15 robotic missions led by various NASA centers have laid the groundwork for future human missions to the Red Planet. The journey to Mars continues with additional robotic missions planned for 2016 and 2020, and human missions in the 2030s.",
        "nasa_id": "50 Years of Mars Exploration ",
        "keywords": [
          "Mars"
        ],
        "date_created": "2015-08-20T00:00:00Z",
        "title": "50 Years of Mars Exploration ",
        "media_type": "video"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: What information do you need to extract? Since `axios` already pass the JSON response into object, you can simple do `this.setState({result:res.data})`

Comment: `Object.values()` will give you the array of content without key. Does this help?

Comment: Fix this: `this.setState = ({`

Comment: I'm trying to access the stuff within the object i.e. center, description, etc..

Comment: Do I need to use Object.keys to acess that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get title to search which .map

```
   results: results.map(results => ({
       title : results.data[0].title,
       description : results.data[0].description,

    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const results = [];

res.items.forEach(item => {
    item.data.forEach(d => results.push(d));
});
```

Comment: How can I access those properties within the object though? Doing res.data.items.map(item => item.data.description); to get the description etc.. doesn't work. Do I still have to use Object.keys on the object?

Comment: @NickKinlen what data do you actually want to get?

Comment: I see now `data` is also an array

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I'm getting a "flatten is not a function" error. I'm just trying to access the data that is inside the object.

Comment: @NickKinlen is `data` always an array length 1?

Comment: Edited my answer again